# Django, интернационализация. Разные переводы для одинаковых слов

Tags: python, django

Нужны разные переводы для одинаковых фраз.

Например, пункт меню Главная->Main, а далее в тексте Главная->Index.

Comment: Используйте контекстные маркеры как описано в документации https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/topics/i18n/translation.html

Comment: Спасибо. А как их в шаблонах использовать?

Comment: В той же ссылке есть про контекстные маркеры в шаблонах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для переводов используйте функции из `django.utils.translation`

В случае, когда одно слово должно переводиться по разному в зависимости от контекст, используют `pgettext`, `pgettext_lazy` , где первым аргументом выступает слово, обозначающее смысл перевода, уточнение, а вторым - переводимое слово или фраза

```
pgettext_lazy('house', 'Home'); # Дом
pgettext_lazy('page', 'Home'); # Главная
```

В результате, в файлах переводов после генерации будет доп строка, указыывающая на контекст

```
msgctxt "house"
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Дом"

msgctxt "page"
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Главная"
```

Для перевода в `django` шаблонах, есть шаблонные теги.

Подключаются через `{% load i18n %}`

Используются почти так же - указывается контекст, если слово может быть переведено на разные варианты.

```
{% load i18n %}
{% translate "Home" context "page" %}
{% translate "Home" context "house %}

{% blocktranslate context "house" %}Home{% endblocktranslate %}
{% blocktranslate context "page" %}Home{% endblocktranslate %}
```

Источник:

- [Документация templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag)
- [Документация contextual markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: можете привести пример шаблона с разной английской фразой и одинаковым русским переводом для нее?

Comment: А в чем смысл? Ориентируйтесь исходя от того языка, на котором написали в коде. Если слова явно отличаются на исходном языке, и другого контекста не будет - без разницы как переводить.